# Nodejs one-time user message

Tags: node.js, pug

I am trying to implement a one-time user message that is passed from the backend nodejs to the browser via req.session through a jade tamplate.

This needs to be implemented WITHOUT the use of websockets.

Whilst the message works and gets passed through to the browser, I am unable to only call it once, and my attempt at deleting the message from the req.session object after sending it does not work.

```
// app.js
if(req.session.user_id == 'XXX') req.session.udata.message = "Hello World";

// route - index.js
res.render('index', { title:'Page Title','udata':req.session.udata});
req.session.udata.message = null;
delete req.session.udata.message;
```

How can I achieve this one-time only ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
app.js

```
var firstTime = true; //Global
if(firstTime){
    if(req.session.user_id == 'XXX') req.session.udata.message = "Hello World";
}
```

index.js

```
res.render('index', { title:'Page Title','udata':req.session.udata});
firstTime = false;
req.session.udata.message = null;
delete req.session.udata.message;
```

This happens the first time every request comes in.